# Periodic nature of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Generally speaking without solving, how are periodic function solutions a priori

recognized by any inspection or computation of terms contained in their ODEs?

(Prior knowledge is a not  a mathematical criterion!)

If and when it is recognized belonging to a class satisfying some rationale how is the

frequency or time period next determined ?

Comment: Is this ODE linear? Constant coefficients?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner. My query is " generally speaking " ..relevant to all the cases.

Comment: Then "generally speaking" you can  say nothing a priory. The constant coefficient linear systems $\dot x=Ax +b$ are completely  determined by matrix $A$. Systems with time dependent coefficients are more complicated but certain classes can be resolved completely too. Nonlinear systems - there is tonnas of literature. But there is no such magic rule "genarally speaking"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is [Floquet Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory), which studies solutions to $\dot{x}=A(t)x$ where the matrix $A(t)$ is *periodic*: $A(t+T)=A(t)$, where $T$ is the period. Loosely speaking, the achievement of this theory is that any solution $x$ to this equation is of the form $e^{iat}P(t)$, where $P(t)$ is a periodic function.

Comment: The converse is also true; if a function is periodic, then there is a differential equation of this form which it solves.